# Symfony 6, EasyAdmin 4, Custom Filters problem

Tags: symfony, filter, easyadmin

I have an entity Company, for clients and suppliers

Products can be assigned to a supplier, and to a client (both), with 2 different foreign keys to the same Company entity.

All is working OK until, in a list of products, I added two custom filters, for clients and suppliers. If I use two default filter, both will show all companies (including clients and suppliers).

This is the code for clients filter (supplier is similar just changing the type value:

Class ClientFilterType

```
namespace App\Form\Type\Admin;

use App\Entity\Company;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ClientFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
          'class' => Company::class,
          'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                      ->andWhere('c.type = :type_id')
                      ->setParameter('type_id', 2)
                      ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
                    }
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent(): ?string
    {
        return EntityType::class;
    }
}
```

Class ClientFilter:

```
namespace App\Controller\Admin\Filter;

use App\Form\Type\Admin\ClientFilterType;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Contracts\Filter\FilterInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\FieldDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\FilterDataDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Filter\FilterTrait;

class ClientFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    use FilterTrait;

    public static function new(string $propertyName, $label = null): self
    {
        return (new self())
            ->setFilterFqcn(__CLASS__)
            ->setProperty($propertyName)
            ->setLabel($label)
            ->setFormType(ClientFilterType::class);
    }

    public function apply(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, FilterDataDto $filterDataDto, ?FieldDto $fieldDto, EntityDto $entityDto): void
    {
        if ('' !== $filterDataDto->getValue()) {
            $queryBuilder
                      ->andWhere('entity.client = :value')
                      ->setParameter('value', $filterDataDto->getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

If I use only one filter, results are OK, but if I use both, client value override supplier value!!!

Doctrine log lookig for supplier selected 13:

```
[doctrine.DEBUG] Executing statement: SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.name AS name_1, c0_.short_name AS short_name_2, c0_.code_name AS code_name_3, c0_.cif AS cif_4, c0_.email AS email_5, c0_.adress AS adress_6, c0_.city AS city_7, c0_.state AS state_8, c0_.zip AS zip_9, c0_.status AS status_10, c0_.type_id AS type_id_11, c0_.country_id AS country_id_12 FROM company c0_ WHERE c0_.type_id = ? AND c0_.id IN (?) ORDER BY c0_.name ASC (parameters: array{"1":1,"2":"13"}, types: array{"1":1,"2":1})
```

Doctrine log lookig for products of supplier selected 13:

```
[doctrine.DEBUG] Executing statement: SELECT count(p0_.id) AS sclr_0 FROM product p0_ WHERE p0_.supplier_id = ? (parameters: array{"1":13}, types: array{"1":1})
```

Doctrine log lookig for supplier selected 13 and client selected 3:

```
[doctrine.DEBUG] Executing statement: SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.name AS name_1, c0_.short_name AS short_name_2, c0_.code_name AS code_name_3, c0_.cif AS cif_4, c0_.email AS email_5, c0_.adress AS adress_6, c0_.city AS city_7, c0_.state AS state_8, c0_.zip AS zip_9, c0_.status AS status_10, c0_.type_id AS type_id_11, c0_.country_id AS country_id_12 FROM company c0_ WHERE c0_.type_id = ? AND c0_.id IN (?) ORDER BY c0_.name ASC (parameters: array{"1":1,"2":"13"}, types: array{"1":1,"2":1})

[doctrine.DEBUG] Executing statement: SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.name AS name_1, c0_.short_name AS short_name_2, c0_.code_name AS code_name_3, c0_.cif AS cif_4, c0_.email AS email_5, c0_.adress AS adress_6, c0_.city AS city_7, c0_.state AS state_8, c0_.zip AS zip_9, c0_.status AS status_10, c0_.type_id AS type_id_11, c0_.country_id AS country_id_12 FROM company c0_ WHERE c0_.type_id = ? AND c0_.id IN (?) ORDER BY c0_.name ASC (parameters: array{"1":2,"2":"3"}, types: array{"1":1,"2":1})
```

Doctrine log looking for products of client 3... and supplier 3 !!!!

```
[doctrine.DEBUG] Executing statement: SELECT DISTINCT p0_.id AS id_0 FROM number p0_ WHERE p0_.supplier_id = ? AND p0_.client_id = ? LIMIT 50 (parameters: array{"1":3,"2":3}, types: array{"1":1,"2":1})
```

So I can't select both filters, client and supplier, at the same time...

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score -2):

Hi just change the parameter name in each qb (value, value1..). I solved the same problem for me. I hope this answer can help.